# How to reverse each word (individually) in a string?

Tags: java, string, reverse

Java Experts need your help.

Today I was asked this questions in one of the interviews which I could not solve it.
So I need a solution as to how should I solve this ;

Reversing a String

```
Input  : Hello, World!
Output : olleH, dlroW!
```

In this case alphanumerics reverses and rest remains in the same place that means comma and Exclamation remains in their same place.

*You can make use of **only** 4 String functions to get the answer;*

1. charAt(c)
2. length()
3. setCharAt(i,c)
4. boolean isAlphaNumeric()

I tried the following code ;

```
public void String(String str){     
    String temp;

    for(int i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        temp = temp + str.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

But the above code reverses the whole string.

Comment: Careful of the words you use: "inplace" generally means in the same memory location without creating another copy. And, since Java strings are immutable, that's impossible.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String reverseString(String str){     
        String temp = "", result = "";
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
            if ( (str.charAt(i)>='A' && str.charAt(i)<='Z')
                || (str.charAt(i)>='a' && str.charAt(i)<='z')
                || (str.charAt(i)>='0' && str.charAt(i)<='9') )
                temp = str.charAt(i) + temp;
            else {
                result += temp + str.charAt(i);
                temp = "";
            }

        result += temp;
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Should make use of the 4th method: `isAlphaNumeric()`

Comment: +1 I believe this is correct answer. Anyway, for its little upgraded version visit http://pastebin.com/FWmaCmEz

Answer (score 2):

You can try to find all words with regex and then use Matchers method [`appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and `appendTail` to replace founded words with reversed version. To produce reversed version of word you can use

```
StringBuilder().append(word).reverse().toString();
```

Here is how you can do it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{IsAlphabetic}+");

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    Matcher m = p.matcher("Hello, World!");
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, reverseWord(m.group()));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    System.out.println(sb);
}

private static String reverseWord(String word) {
    return new StringBuilder().append(word).reverse().toString();
}
```

output:

```
olleH, dlroW!
```

Comment: +1 Very nice. I never how understood appendReplacement/appendTail before! It also seems like this should show up someone in an answer to my recent question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737653/one-off-equivalent-for-regex-replace-with-function-evaluation)

Comment: While I'd use this answer in real life, the OP has some silly interview requirements: "You can make use of only 4 String functions to get the answer ; 1) charAt(c) 2) length() 3) setCharAt(i,c) 4) boolean isAlphaNumeric()"

Comment: @hasan That is why I upvoted your answer. Anyway in real life you could upgrade it even more using enhanced for loop like `for (char ch: str.toCharArray()){...}`, appending to StringBuilder instead of `someString += anotherString` in loop and using `Character.isDigit(ch)||Character.isAlphabetic(ch)` in `if`. Anyway your answer should be accepted one.

Comment: isAlphaNumeric() is a method in StringUtils class which is not a java native class. I can use Character.isLetterOrDigit

Answer (score 0):

Start by splitting the string into words using `str.split('[^a-zA-Z]')`.

Then loop through the array and reverse each part as you did above. Finally, join the string together again. To get an array of separators in order, just use `str.split('[a-zA-Z]')`

Example:

```
String[] words=str.split('[^a-zA-Z]');
String[] separators=str.split('[a-zA-Z]');

//Left as an exercise: reverse each element of the words array (as you did in the original question)

int offset=0;
//Left as an exercise: If the sentence starts with punctuation, increment offset by one and insert the punctuation at the beginning

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
{
    sb.append(words[i]);
    if(i+offset<separators.length)
    {
        sb.append(separators[i+offset]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I just read the changes to the question specifying which methods can be used. It is fairly simple to replace split with a manual implementation for this specific case, and I leave it as an exercise. This answer is meant to be a pseudocode idea for how to implement this task, not a copy-paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

setCharAt isn't string functions as String is immutable, however you can do this with either a char array or a StringBuilder (which just wraps a char array). isAlphaNumeric isn't a standard method anywhere that I can find however Character.isAlphabetic is what I believe you want. This is using as close as I could get to following your restrictions:

```
private static CharSequence reverseWords( CharSequence in )
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( in );
    for( int i = 0, len = sb.length(); i < len; i++ )
    {
        if( Character.isAlphabetic( sb.charAt( i ) ) )
        {
            int end = i;
            while( ++end < len && Character.isAlphabetic( sb.charAt( end ) ) );
            int j = end - 1;
            while( j > i )
            {
                char temp = sb.charAt( i );
                sb.setCharAt( i++, sb.charAt( j ) );
                sb.setCharAt( j--, temp );
            }
            i = end;
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

However if you wanted to use a char array directly without a StringBuilder:

```
private static String reverseWords( String in )
{
    char[] chars = in.toCharArray();
    for( int i = 0, len = chars.length; i < len; i++ )
    {
        if( Character.isAlphabetic( chars[i] ) )
        {
            int end = i;
            while( ++end < len && Character.isAlphabetic( chars[end] ) );
            int j = end - 1;
            while( j > i )
            {
                char temp = chars[i];
                chars[i++] = chars[j];
                chars[j--] = temp;
            }
            i = end;
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf( chars );
}
```