# What is the equivalent of Regex-replace-with-function-evaluation in Java 7?

Tags: java, regex, function, replace, matchevaluator

I'm looking for a *very simple* way of getting the equivalent of something like the following JavaScript code. That is, for each match I would like to call a certain transformation function and use the result as the replacement value.

```
var res = "Hello World!".replace(/\S+/, function (word) {
    // Since this function represents a transformation,
    // replacing literal strings (as with replaceAll) are not a viable solution.
    return "" + word.length;
})
// res => "5 6"
```

Only .. in Java. And, preferably as a "single method" or "template" that can be reused.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your answer is in the [Matcher#appendReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) documentation. Just put your function call in the while loop.

> [The appendReplacement method] is intended to be used in a loop together with the appendTail and find methods. The following code, for example, writes one dog two dogs in the yard to the standard-output stream:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cat");
Matcher m = p.matcher("one cat two cats in the yard");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "dog");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1282099/20938) is a more complete solution.  It deals with the problem of dollar signs and backslashes being treated as special by `appendReplacement()`.

Answer (score 17):

When allowing Java 8 you can use Lambda-Expressions, to have a JavaScript like replace:

```
String result = StringReplacer.replace("Hello World!", Pattern.compile("\\S+"), m -> ("" + m.group().length()));
```

StringReplacer.java:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringReplacer {
    public static String replace(String input, Pattern regex, Function<Matcher, String> callback) {
        StringBuffer resultString = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(input);
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            regexMatcher.appendReplacement(resultString, callback.apply(regexMatcher));
        }
        regexMatcher.appendTail(resultString);

        return resultString.toString();
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.whitebyte.info/programming/string-replace-with-callback-in-java-like-in-javascript

Comment: You might want to call `Matcher.quoteReplacement` on the replacement string, to avoid slashes and dollar signs being treated specially.

Comment: @Gareth it would be awesome if you could fork the [gist](https://gist.github.com/nickrussler/42f8619f1a36eea25364), improve it and comment back with the link. I'll then update the post and my gist ASAP.

Answer (score 17):

#### Since Java 9 [`Matcher.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)):

```java
Pattern.compile("\\S+").matcher("Hello World!")
       .replaceAll(mr -> "" + mr.group().length());
```

The parameter freely named `mr` is a `MatchResult`, with access methods like `mr.group(1)` or `mr.end() - mr.start()`.

Comment: *Finally* .. :|

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your precise requirements are but something like this could work:

```
String res = "";
for (String piece : "hello world".split(" "))
  res += Integer.toString(piece.length()) + " ";
```

Of course there are other ways to write that, and tweaks that can be made depending on requirements (e.g. use a more accurate delimiter than a space).

For a precise implementation of your snippet, you could use e.g. `StreamTokenizer` with a `StringReader` and some wrappers to parse out the delimiters and insert them between the counts.

Comment: While this would work here, I'm looking for a solution that can remain generic (through utilizing regular expression support).