# What is the equivalent of Regex-replace-with-function-evaluation in Java 8?

Tags: java, regex, replace, transformation, java-8

I have a String like this `"4 + 5 = 9;"` and I want to add one to each number found.

I want to use regular expressions and a transformation function for every match.

I know how to do it in Java <= 7. It is in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737653/what-is-the-equivalent-of-regex-replace-with-function-evaluation-in-java-7).

I want to know if there is something new about this in Java 8.

EDIT:
This is my best try:

```
private static String regexTransform(String regex, String input,
        Function<String, String> function) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
       m.appendReplacement(sb, function.apply(m.group()));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

String res = regexTransform("[0-9]+", "4 + 5 = 9;", s-> String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(s) + 1));
System.out.println(res); // 5 + 6 = 10
```

Comment: Doesn't look like there is anything new in the Java 8 [docs](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) with respect to this.

Comment: looks good, think its the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `stream-api` to achieve this.

We can do the following:

```
String input = "4 + 5 = 9;";

String out = input.chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char) i))
        .map(s -> s.matches("[0-9]") ? String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(s) + 1)) : s)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(out);    // prints 5 + 6 = 10;
```

Comment: That approach only works with 1 char (or delimited) strings without a context. Try the same with `a+1= 6`.

Comment: Can't get what you mean, But the the result of `a+1= 6` is `a+2= 7`.