# What's the best way to url encode only query keys and params in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, urlencode, url-encoding

I would like to encode only the query keys and parameters of a url (don't want to encode the /, ? or &). What's the best way to do this in Java?

For example, I want to convert

`http://www.hello.com/bar/foo?a=,b &c =d`

to

`http://www.hello.com/bar/foo?a=%2Cb%20&c%20=d`

Comment: Extract and parse the query components; rebuild the URL. Practically, I would use a regular expression replace with the appropriate encoding applied on the replacement. The pattern for the supplied URL, with captures, might look like: `\b(\w[^=]*)=([^&]*)`

Comment: `URL url = new URL(...); String query = URLEncoder.encode(url.getQuery(), ...); String encoded = url.getPath() + "?" + query;` or something like that; I don't recall the specifics of the various `URL.getXXX()`'s off the top of my head.

Comment: @user2864740 You can just use `URL` to parse and extract the components; and `URLEncoder` is part of the JDK as well and encodes arbitrary strings.

Comment: @JasonC Perhaps, but I'm not confident enough on how the first URL will be parsed as it requires some "leniency" - particularly on the the "c " parameter name in this case; it may also require additional relaxed parsing if different unescaped/reserved characters were also included.

Answer (score 0):

Build the url something like this:

```
String url = "http://www.hello.com/bar/foo?";
url += "a=" + URLEncoder.encode(value_of_a);
url += "&c=" + URLEncoder.encode(value_of_c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave the actual [component encoding as a user-supplied function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330104/encoding-url-query-parameters-in-java?lq=1) because it is an existing well-discussed problem without a trivial [JCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library) solution .. In any case, the following is how I would approach this *particular* problem without the use of third-party libraries.

While regular expressions sometimes result in [two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/), I am hesitant to suggest a more strict approach such as [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) because I don't know how it will - or even if it will - work with such funky invalid URLs. As such, here is a solution using a regular expression with a [dynamic replacement value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737653/what-is-the-equivalent-of-regex-replace-with-function-evaluation-in-java-7).

```
// The following pattern is pretty liberal on what it matches;
// It ought to work as long as there is no unencoded ?, =, or & in the URL
// but, being liberal, it will also match absolute garbage input.
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w[^=?]*)=([^&]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("http://www.hello.com/bar/foo?a=,b &c =d");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    String key = m.group(1);
    String value = m.group(2);
    m.appendReplacement(sb,
        encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" encodeURIComponent(value));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

See the [ideone example](http://ideone.com/53PqDj) example with a fill-in `encodeURIComponent`.