# How can I do string replace with lambda function in Java

Tags: java, regex, replace, lambda, replaceall

In JavaScript it's possible to use lambda functions with the replace function, in Java string.replaceAll will not allow this. How can I do the same thing in as below in Java?:

```
replaceDotHandlesWithUnderscore(input) {
  // e.g. {my.nested.value} to {my_nested_value}
  // e.g. {my.nested.value, select, true {Yes} false {No}} to {my_nested_value, select, true {Yes} no {false}}
  return input.replace(
    /\{(\s*)(\w+(\.\w+)*)/g,
    (matches, space, handle) => `{${space}${handle.replace(/\./g, '_')}`
  );
}
```

It's fine to go with Java 1.8 or 1.9 solutions to this.

Comment: why would `String.replaceAll` not do this?

Comment: @nullpointer there is no way to use a callback inside `replaceAll`, but there is [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/377484/3832970) (also, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737857/3832970)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Looking at the *eg* in the code looked simple to me, maybe I don' understand the code in javascript there.

Comment: @nullpointer That is ES6 syntax. `matches` is the match value, `space` is capturing group 1, `handle` is Group 2 value. They are used in an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew with that example and https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/regex/matcher-appendreplacement-example-part-2/ I think I can find my way now :)