# Capture html tag with attributes and values?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a complete html file input as string(I have file also) in java. Text is something like below

```
Sample input
    Some text........... <s:message code="code1" arguments="${arg1,arg2}" />..
    some text  ........
    some text  ....... <s:message code="code2" 
     />...........
```

Basically I need to replace all text  based on code type. For example if code is code1 then replace the s:message tag with test1

```
sample output
    Some text........... test1..
    some text  ........
    some text  ....... test2 ...........
```

I am not getting how to capture complete `<s:message  >` and then replace it with some other text ? Looks like i need to use regex here but
not getting how to start ?

**Update :-**

code1 and test1 are just examples and they can be any value. code1 can be xyz and can be replaced by abc. That's why i want to capture all message tags(either one by one while traversing or in one go) ,then get the code , do some logic and see what will be the replacement value.

**Approach 2:-**
There is another way I can do it, I have list of codes in data structure, For each code check if there is in any enclosing message tag, capture it and then process it.

Comment: Try [`<s:message\b[^>]*?"code(\d+)"[^>]*>`](https://regex101.com/r/8TrzgJ/2)

Comment: Why would you need to do such operation in the first place? Could it be possible do find an easier way than regex?

Comment: @YassinHajaj There is some business need which i want to automate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be XML and you would better use a parser to find the node and replace it with the text you want. Doing this with Regular Expressions is rather a make-or-break (especially when your conditions go up). But here is a solution for this  specific problem:

```
String regex = '<s:message\\b[^>]*?"code(\\d+)"[^>]*>';
```

and replace match with `test$1`:

```
string = string.replaceAll(regex, "test$1");
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/9tXQrr)

Comment: I don't know if OP cares but this wouldn't work for `<s:message code="<code2>" />` or similar cases. Again, don't know if OP cares, this could be good

Comment: @YassinHajaj To me *For example if code **is** code1* means `code="code1"`. I mean I don't infer *includes* from it but if you do that would be something totally different.

Comment: @revo  code1 and test1 are just examples and they can be any value. code1 can be xyz and can be replaced by abc. That's why i want to capture all message tags(either one by one while traversing or in one go) ,then get the code , do some logic and see what will be the replacement value.

Comment: @revo see if approach 2 is easy to implement in my post if original requirement is bit trickier ?

Comment: @emilly You have changed whole requirements now. If you need to work around replacement string based on captured data then you will need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737653/what-is-the-equivalent-of-regex-replace-with-function-evaluation-in-java-7

Comment: @revo Actually i am not getting how to capture the enclosing message tag if I know the text in code

Comment: If you know or if you don't know? @emilly

Comment: I have list of possible text values that cam come under `code` attribute of message tag. I want to capture the complete message tag around that code.

Comment: @emilly Iterate over list items and use current regex to replace the item but instead `code(\\d+)` use the current item.

Comment: @revo I have posted separate question for the same with clear description. Actually I first need to capture the message tag instead of straightaway implementation. Here is the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199958/finding-enclosing-tag. Accepting the answer based on first post.

Comment: @revo your suggestion to use the current item instead of` `code(\\d+)` did not work. I used regex  as `String regex = "<s:message\\b[^>]*?\"code(\\"+textToFound+"+)\"[^>]*>"` in java. It says `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: \k is not followed by '<' for named capturing group near index 26`

Comment: @emilly I said instead of `code(\\d+)` not `d+`. Your other question is closed unfortunately.

Comment: Can't I capture the enclosing message tag with the help of some readymade  library (like jsoup parser or something else) or some other way ? Can't wite full parser :(